# Why is the letter "F" used for the curvature 2-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, math-history

Given a differentiable manifold $X$, a vector bundle $E\to X$ and a connection $A$ on $E$. The curvature $2$-form of the connection is a $2$-form with values on the endomorphisms of $E$ defined as $$F(A)=dA + A \wedge A.$$ 
My question is: **Why the letter "F" seems to be the standard choice of symbol for the curvature form?**.

At least all the references I am using use have chosen to use this letter.

Comment: [My guess](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=flexion&allowed_in_frame=0).

Answer (score 4):

I suspect this originates in Minkowski's use of it for the electromagnetic tensor in his famous paper on electromagnetism in special relativity, [*The Fundamental Equations for Electromagnetic Processes in Moving Bodies*](http://en.wikisource.org/?curid=674267)

In particular, notice his use of $F_{12}$ &c. in [this section](http://en.wikisource.org/?curid=674267#.C2.A7_7._Fundamental_Equations_for_bodies_at_rest.).

(Why *he* uses $F$, I don't know.)

Comment: F for field !(?)

Answer (score 2):

One reason is that the pull back of the curvature 2-form via a local section of the principal bundle is called the "gauge field strength" and is denoted by F.

BTW: A gauge field is just the pull back of the connection 1-form via a local section.

Here is a reference

http://empg.maths.ed.ac.uk/Activities/GT/Lect2.pdf